# Rotated CSS Box Shadow

Tags: html, css

All can anyone tell me how i could possible get this rotated shadow to an image using CSS?

If possible also with the border radius done in CSS

[image]

Comment: answer is given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941277/only-css-rotate-box-shadow-without-original-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably have to create a transparent element with the shadow applied and rotate that behind your image. Something like:

```
<div class="img-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="img-shadow" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;"></div>
    <div class="img" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2;"></div>
</div>
```

SO isn't a "free freelancer" service, so give it a try and update your question with any issues you encounter.